# How can a developer access the Cardano network?

Tags: api, mainnet, testnet

As a developer building an application, what are different way to access the Cardano network?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are also ways to use services where you can make API requests to interact with the Cardano blockchain. (without the need to run your own cardano-node)

You could for example [sign in on Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io/auth/signin) with your GitHub account. No registration required. Enter a project name and select Cardano mainnet or Cardano testnet, depending on your needs.

After generating your `API KEY` you can send your first request to get data for example about the latest epoch:

`curl -H 'project_id: 1234567890' https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/epochs/latest`

And you will get a response in JSON format similar to this:

`{ "epoch": 225,   "start_time": 1603403091, "end_time": 1603835086, "first_block_time": 1603403092, "last_block_time": 1603835084, "block_count": 21298, "tx_count": 17856, "output": "7849943934049314", "fees": "4203312194", "active_stake": "784953934049314" }`

Visit [docs.blockfrost.io](https://docs.blockfrost.io) to see the complete API documentation.

Answer (score 22):

If you use Nix or NixOs, it is rather straightforward: [Build the code for a cardano node using nix](https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/getting-started/building-the-node-using-nix.html) (link to current documentation)

Duplicating the official documentation:

```
git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node
cd cardano-node
nix-build -A scripts.mainnet.node -o mainnet-node-local
./mainnet-node-local
```

This will run a cardano node on the mainnet.

Then you can also build and use the CLI tool to interact with the cardano network.

---

In the provided solution above, if you don't want to compile GHC which can take a long time, IOHK provides many binaries that are pre-compiled for you: lots of time gained ! So don't hesitate to use their nix binary cache

In NixOS, I currently set it this way:

```
# configuration.nix
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
{
  # ... all the rest of the configuration of the server

  # iohk binary caches
  nix = 
  {
    binaryCaches          = [ "https://hydra.iohk.io" "https://iohk.cachix.org" ];
    binaryCachePublicKeys = [ "hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ=" "iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo=" ];
  };
}
```

Comment: Running this command "./mainnet-node-local" will download the whole blockchain or not?

Comment: @vs4vijay when running this command, it creates a folder `state-node-mainnet/db-mainnet` which size increases overtime. I'm fairly confindent it is the state of the blockchain

Comment: This will get even nicer soon. It should become as simple as `nix run github:input-output-hk/cardano-node/1.28.0#something`. without even having to clone the repo locally. something isn't quite defined yet, but will be similar to the path building the script above.

Answer (score 10):

Generally, there are several options you could pursue.

- Start a stake pool on test-net and then launch one on main-net.
  [How to build a Cardano Stake Pool.](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node)
- Get involved with project catalyst. Offer feedback and input to projects that interest you. Try to get involved with a team that has promising ideas. Offer your services where you can fit in.
  [Project Catalyst Ideascale.](https://cardano.ideascale.com/)
- Try building smart contracts using Marlowe. [Marlowe Playground.](https://alpha.marlowe.iohkdev.io/#/)
- Mint your own native token on Cardano. [FAQ : Native Tokens (Cardano’s Multi-Asset Support Feature)](https://cardano-ledger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/explanations/faq.html)
- Follow along with the videos for the Plutus Pioneers Program and learn to write smart contracts in Cardano's on chain programming language. [Plutus Pioneers Program on YouTube](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK8ah7DzglhhJzuiz7X33UCHSTYPB-8Jt)
- Figure out how to mint some NFTs...
- Integration with Atala Prism for identity and certification. [Atala PRISM](https://atalaprism.io/app)

I'm sure there are lots of other possibilities that I haven't heard of or considered. There is no shortage of room to explore for a developer.